# How to select part of a custom element with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

To select all elements that start with the class name `foo`. I can use:
`[class^="foo"] { }`

What can I use to select a custom *element* that starts with `foo`.

Example:

```
<foo-bar>Hola</foo-bar>
<foo-bazz>Hola</foo-bazz>
```

I want to have a single selector for both elements.

Comment: There is no contains/starts with/ends with selector for an element type currently. That is possible only for attributes.

Comment: Aha, that would explain why I can't find it :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The `[...]` selectors only work on attributes, not element types themselves.

What you can do though, as I'm sure you're already aware, is chain them all into one selectors group, but this will mean that you'll need to know the exact element names:

```css
foo-bar,
foo-bazz {
  ...
}
```

Failing that, you can always just give them all a shared `class` or `data-*` attribute:

```
<foo-bar class="foo"></foo-bar>
<foo-bazz class="foo"></foo-bazz>
```

```css
.foo {
  ...
}
```